# Python ; Go back to a line if condition = false

Tags: python

In my Title I mean that :

```
    myCellar = ["doritos", "chips", "chocolates", ""]
    productsInDemand = input("Write a product : ")

   for supply in myCellar :
      if productsInDemand == supply:
         print("This product we have : '",productsInDemand ,"'")
         break
   else:
      print("This product we have not : '",productsInDemand ,"'")
      (go back to the line 1)
```

If I will write a product that does not excist in 'mycellar' then the program will go back to the first line to write again a product .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use an infinite `while True` loop:

```
while True:
    myCellar = ["doritos", "chips", "chocolates", ""]
    productsInDemand = input("Write a product : ")
    if productsInDemand in myCellar:
        print("This product we have : '", productsInDemand, "'")
        break
    print("This product we have not : '", productsInDemand, "'")
```

Comment: I would put `myCellar = ["doritos", "chips", "chocolates", ""]` before the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
myCellar = ["doritos", "chips", "chocolates", ""]
productsInDemand = input("Write a product : ")

while productsInDemand not in myCellar :
    print("This product we have not : '",productsInDemand ,"'")
    productsInDemand = input("Write a product : ")

print("This product we have : '",productsInDemand ,"'")
```

**output:**

```
Write a product : foo
This product we have not : ' foo '
Write a product : bar
This product we have not : ' bar '
Write a product : doritos
This product we have : ' doritos '
```